# Email rejections after moving MX record

Tags: email, dns, exchange-server, cpanel, mx-record

I recently moved my email from my own domain (hosted with Vidahost) to Exchange Online. Everything seems to be working fine with regards to genuine email arriving at my Exchange account, however I am getting strange mail rejection notifications on my Vidahost account.

The MX record has been changed correctly and there is only 1 record, so I'm a bit confused how the rejections are coming back to Vidahost? An example is as follows (from CPanel Email Trace):

```
Email was rejected at SMPT time by an RBL, filter or other configuration
Event: rejected
User: -remote-   
Sender: (random invalid addresses, progresses through alphabet)eg huggins @ mydomain  
Sender Host: customer-189-217-55-58.cablevision.net.mx   
Sender IP Address: 189.217.55.58  
Authentication: unauthorized 
Spam Score: 0 
Recipient: as sender  
Router: reject  
Transport: **rejected**  
Delivery Host: customer-189-217-55-58.cablevision.net.mx  
Delivery IP Address: 189.217.55.58 
Size: 0 bytes 
Result: JunkMail rejected - (customer-189-217-55-58.cablevision.net.mx)   [189.217.55.58]:38159 is in an RBL, see http://dnsbl.invaluement.com/lookup/?item=189.217.55.58
```

A vast majority of the recipient and senders are set to invalid accounts on my domain, but none are actually originating from my domain (the host has also verified this). Exchange Online is rejecting any email sent to a non-account on my domain, how are these then making their way back to Vidahost even though the MX record doesn't point there?

Any help greatly received!

Comment: This question seems a little off topic here. My guess would be that the spammer looked up your MX (and probably your A) some weeks ago and has not bothered to do a new lookup since then.

Answer (score 0):

I can see server IP 189.217.55.58 is blacklisted at ivmSIP and due to that you are getting this issues, Please check it at : http://www.invaluement.com/research/?item=189.217.55.58

Comment: Yes, I did notice that but doesn't explain why the traffic is still arriving at the old MX, I expect Christoph may be right above.

Answer (score 0):

This is Rob McEwen from invaluement. We really did have egregious spam sent from 189.217.55.58 a few days ago. I just took a look at a sample after reading your post above. It is unquestionably some nasty and unsolicited (and pornographic, btw) spam. But since this was a one-off incident, your IP expired off my blacklist quickly, so ti is no longer listed.

Regarding your actual question.

The reason that some messages are going to the old server is because spammers often store the IPs that MX records resolve to in their databases, to be used for direct sending. They then send to the IP even after the MX has long migrated. (and I'm assuming that the other actual legit mail isn't effected because the name server changes already had time for the MX to fully propagate?)

One thing you should also do... is whenever moving your MX to a new provider, it is a good idea to (soon after the move), to get your old provider to:

(a) delete your domain from their mail server, and

(b) also make sure that they don't have your domain in their name server... which can sometimes happen even if your registrar record never pointed to them as the name server (unfortunately, some hosters just auto-set up that way)

hope this helps...